# NodeJS – Serialport Readline issue

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

after my first question ([NodeJS and Serialport – Read RFID Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69062774/nodejs-and-serialport-read-rfid-card)) I figured out a way to get the correct data.

But now my result is the following:

```
data received:
data received: 0
data received: >
data received: 0
data received: 0
data received: 6
data received: 3
data received: 4
data received: :
data received: ;
data received: 4
data received:
```

my desired output is the following

```
0>00634:;4
```

how can I achieve this using this code:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline');

var sp = new SerialPort('/dev/tty.usbserial-0001', {
    parser: new Readline(' '),
    baudRate: 4800,
    parity: 'none',
    newline: ' ',
});

sp.on('open', function () {
    console.log('open');
    sp.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('data received: ' + data.toString());
    });
});
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what exactly you mean by `archive`, however, incase you want to filter out the empty data you could just use the `data.toString()` output in an `if` statement.

Example:

```js
sp.on('data', function (data) => {
    const stringData = data.toString();

    if (stringData) {
        console.log(`data received: ${stringData}`);
    }
});
```

And if you would want to write this data to a file you could simply add:

```js
fs.appendFileSync('output.bin', stringData);
```

In the data callback, you can decide yourself if you want to append the blank data or not by either putting it in or out of the `if` statement.

### Edit

Based on some updated information the following would be the answer. To seperate the information, the data event should be the following:

```js
// Putting the package in a higher scope to make sure that the contents stay after the data event
let package = "";

sp.on('data', function (data) => {
    const stringData = data.toString();

    if (stringData) {
        package += stringData;
    } else {
        // All the string processing goes here, use package for the result

        package = ""; // Resetting the package to collect the next package
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry I meant "achieve". I've tried your solution but it seems that nothing has changed in the output. Right now I get every Char as a single line but I want to get that data in one String, so I can perform an if statement afterwords like this: if(data.length === 10){...}.

Comment: I've updated my answer using this information.

Comment: thanks, works like a charm :-)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.